# Core Graphics CGPathRef drawn at a specified point

Tags: ios, macos, core-graphics

I have a "palette" of paths that I will draw many times; perhaps 100.

I'd like to draw these at a specified location like this:

```
CGPathRef foo = ...
CGPathRef bar = ...
// do this dozens of times at differing points
[self draw:context path:foo atX:100 andY:50];
[self draw:context path:bar atX:200 andY:50];
```

What I'm doing now is translating. It works, but I'm not sure that this is the most performant solution. Something like this:

```
- (CGRect) draw:(CGContextRef) context path:(CGPathRef) path atX:(CGFloat) x andY:   (CGFloat)y
{
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, x, y);
    CGRect pathBoundingRect = CGPathGetBoundingBox(path);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, drawColor);
    CGContextAddPath(context, path);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    return pathBoundingRect;
}
```

Do you have any suggestions for improvement?

Answer (score 0):

If they move, it would probably be much faster to draw each one in its own UIView (so in the beginning, they would all be identical), and position the view itself.

That way, the translation (of the views) would automatically be done on the GPU instead of the CPU, and `drawRect:` would only need to be called once for each path object.

Comment: Thanks fzwo. Interesting idea; create views that draw the path and add the view as subviews to the "canvas" view. The paths won't move, but I'll try it and compare the results vs. the single view version. I didn't try that because I thought - without evidence - that the subview approach would be less performant.

Comment: UIKit is quite performant for some things. By the way, did you measure that you actually do have a performance problem?